# reactjs and updating state on arrays

Tags: reactjs

its probably some stupid mistake but I can't find out tbh.. Here's my example of state:

```
this.state = {
  data: {
    some data: ['some data']
  }
}
```

Now im trying to delete specific index from an array. Heres my approach:

```
const newArr =  this.state.data[key].filter(item => item !== value);
```

In the code above im getting what I want which is an array without one specific item

```
data: {
   ...this.state.data,
   [key]: newArr
},
```

But it doesnt work.. What is wrong here?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? What is the result you expect and what is the result you get?

Comment: The expected result would be an array without one Item that filter function threw away. Instead of that for some reason values in my array are duplicated. I fire a function on click to set state and after multiple clicks an array grows.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're appending the filtered array to the items in the original array. Is that your intent?

```js
data: {
    ...this.state.data,
    [key]: [
        ...this.state.data[key], // individual entries
        newArr, // array
    ],
},

//result:
data: {
  'some key': [
    "item 1", // string from original
    "item 2", // string from original
    [ "item 1", "item 2"] // array
  ]
}
```

If you just want the filtered items:

```js
data: {
    ...this.state.data,
    [key]: newArr // the filtered array 
},

//result:
data: {
  'some key': [
    "item 2", // filtered items 
  ]
}
```

Comment: hmm good catch. I want to override some key array not adding a new one.. so it should look like this? `data: {
            ...this.state.data,
            [key]: newArr
          },`

Comment: actually my bad.. I had this already. I just put the wrong chunk of code. Unfortunately its not working :/ I have updated the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was my fault. The code itself was correct. State was set up twice because of my mistake.